# ASP.NET WebApi - reference file on server securely

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, asp.net-web-api

Alright, so I would like to create a thumbnail storage with a couple of png image files in it.

I created a directory on the server side. Now in my controller I would like to process requests for images.

Currently the code of my controller looks like this:

```
public class ThumbnailController : ApiController
{
    [Route("api/v1/thumbnail")]
    [HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetThumbnail(string id)
    {
        var result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);

        string filePath = $@"D:\server_data\Images\Thumbnails\{id}.png";
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(filePath) || !File.Exists(filePath)) return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, "Invalid file");

        var image = Image.FromFile(filePath);
        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            image.Save(memoryStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            result.Content = new ByteArrayContent(memoryStream.ToArray());
        }

        result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("image/jpeg");
        return result;
    }
}
```

Now this one has a security issue: if I call something like `http://my.address.com/api/v1/thumbnail?id=../securefile.png` I would essentially get the `securefile.png` image file located in the parent directory. Similarly I could download any png image on the hard drive, which is obviously not desired.

For a reason the thumbnails directory must be detached from the server root, so I guess I can not use something like `string filePath = HostingEnvironment.MapPath($"~/Images/{id}.png");`

To avoid the problem I could trim starting dots or check the incoming `id` for special characters, but it does not feel like the right way to fight it. I wonder if better practices exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trimming starting dots is not enough, consider an input similar to `foo/bar/../../../outside.png`.

You should validate the `id` parameter to only contain say letters, or even better, only numbers. You can achieve complex validation through [validation attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28425570/validation-on-parameters-to-a-webapi-action) or [model validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12163461/validating-manipulating-input-parameters-in-multi-tenant-web-api), both are basically the same. The point is that a user should not be able to enter any special characters, which would effectively mitigate the path injection threat.